# CI/CD in GitLab for ASP.NET Framework Solution

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

I have been trying for the past weeks to accomplish a simple CI/CD pipeline, at least the first step of it. I should note, this is my first time doing anything in CI/CD.

My end goal is to automatically build a solution and release the built files to our staging environment.

The solutions has 3 layers to it, each on a separate project: Data Layer, Services, Web.

Nuget is outputting

```
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
Feeds used:
    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Installed:
    4 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

I am assuming that this result means that all projects / packages.config files have been honored and thus all packages have been downloaded for the solution and 3 csproj, hence why it states 4 package(s).

However, I am getting about 40 to 50 errors similar to these for various files across the board:

```
$ & "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Database\Account.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Database\Account.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My current yaml code is as follows

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\PATH\TO\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\PATH\TO\msbuild.exe'
  PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR: publish

stages:
  - build

build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - branches
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly'

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR
```

Anyone can see any obvious mistakes?

Comment: Are your packages installed in Git, or they are being pulled from the web?  Does your CI server have access to internet connection?  Did you try manually pulling the files on your CI server and issue the build from the command window?  I would suggest do the build manually on your CI server first and work out the bugs, then try to automate via yaml